# Too many failed attempts, SSH is requesting PubKey I didn't set up

Tags: ssh, openssh

I think I, somehow, made too many attempts trying to login to my `root@server` using `ssh`. SSH is now asking for a public key authentication, which I have never set up.

**How do I log back in to my server**, and **how do I permanently disable public key authentication** (yes, I know the risks and I'm willing to take them).

I'm using OpenSSH.

Log:`ssh -vvv root@server`

```
    Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/private/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/private/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/private/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/private/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/private/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/private/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/private/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/private/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@server's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: Are you sure password auth is enabled for root? Because it's not by default.

Comment: God... knowledge is power. I just logged in from another user and yes, you're right, it was disabled. Please add your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH changed the default value for the `PermitRootLogin` option with the [release of version 7.0](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0) (August 2015). The new default value is `prohibit-password`. Previously, the value was `yes`.

Regular users can still authenticate with passwords by default.

Also, while public key authentication could indeed by disabled (`PubkeyAuthentication` option), there’s no benefit to doing so unless you enable some other authentication method. Unless the `AuthenticationMethods` option doesn’t require users to pass multiple methods, any will suffice.